# Can i use rn-samsung-tv-remote to other TV by changing the logics?

Tags: react-native, wifi-direct

I am developing an application that serves as a universal remote control for televisions using Wi-Fi. Currently, I'm testing it with a Philips TV, but I couldn't find a library for Philips, only one for Samsung.

[Lib i found and hope to adapte](https://github.com/ersinayaz/rn-samsung-tv-remote)

My question is, can I adapt this Samsung library to work with other TVs, especially Philips which I'm using for testing? If so, where should I start? If not, does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

[Can i change this line to use for others TVs ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga1o2.png)

Even though I know I don't have a Samsung television, I'm going to share the error I received.

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l8bd.png)

Before that I was testing with react-native-wifi-p2p and managed to find my Philips TV with the getAvailablePeers() method, but then I got stuck without knowing how to send commands to the television.

[wifi-p2p](https://github.com/kirillzyusko/react-native-wifi-p2p)

My goal is to remotely control televisions from different brands using a React Native app and wi-fi. Ideally, I'd like to stick to React Native, but given the approaching deadline and the fact that I haven't made much progress yet, I'm open to suggestions.

[like this app for example](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sensustech.universal.tv.remote.control&pcampaignid=web_share)